# How to trick the macro \pgfkeys into not removing surrounding spaces from values that are put in braces?

Tags: pgfkeys

I tried to use pgfkeys for providing keys' values that have surrounding space-tokens:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{/WeirdKeys/weird/.initial=weird}%
\newcommand\Weird[1]{\pgfkeys{/WeirdKeys/.cd,#1}}%

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

Here I don't want spaces around weird: |\Weird{weird}|.

\Weird{weird={ weird }}

Here I do want spaces around weird: |\Weird{weird}|.

But I don't get them.

It should look like this: | weird |.

Extra effort:

\def\surroundwithspaces#1#2{#1#2#1}

\expandafter\Weird
\expandafter{%
\expandafter w%
\expandafter e%
\expandafter i%
\expandafter r%
\expandafter d%
\expandafter =%
\surroundwithspaces{ }{weird}}

Here I do not get spaces around weird: |\Weird{weird}|.

\def\surroundwithspaces#1#2{#1#1#2#1#1}

\expandafter\Weird
\expandafter{%
\expandafter w%
\expandafter e%
\expandafter i%
\expandafter r%
\expandafter d%
\expandafter =%
\surroundwithspaces{ }{weird}}

Here I do get spaces around weird: |\Weird{weird}|.

\def\surroundwithspaces#1#2{#1#1#1#2#1#1#1}

\expandafter\Weird
\expandafter{%
\expandafter w%
\expandafter e%
\expandafter i%
\expandafter r%
\expandafter d%
\expandafter =%
\surroundwithspaces{ }{weird}}

Here I do get more spaces around weird: |\Weird{weird}|.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, section 87.3 Setting Keys of the pgfmanual says:

`\pgfkeys{⟨key list⟩}`

> The *⟨key list⟩* should be a list of key–value pairs, separated by commas. A key–value pair can have the following two forms: *⟨key*=*value⟩* or just *⟨key⟩*. **Any spaces around the *⟨key⟩* or around the *⟨value⟩* are removed.** It is permissible to surround both the *⟨key⟩* or the *⟨value⟩* in curly braces, which are also removed.** Especially putting the *⟨value⟩* in curly braces needs to be done quite often, namely whenever the *⟨value⟩* contains an equal-sign or a comma.

Seems spaces surrounding the *⟨value⟩* are removed even if the *⟨value⟩* is put in curly braces.

**What can you do against this space-removal?**

Besides this, the statement of *any space* around things being removed seems not correct:

As can be seen in the MWE above, if I put extra effort in hacking consecutive space-tokens before and behind the value, before and behind the value only one of them is removed.

Comment: Yes, `pgfkeys` like many other key=value implementations only strips at most one space from the start and end of a key or value. I *think* the only key=value parser which reliably strips *all* spaces around the key or value before stripping braces is the one provided by `l3keys`. There are other parsers which get the brace-stripping only after space stripping right, though.

Comment: @Skillmon Indeed: I guess in `expkv` you don't use the `\tl_trim_spaces:n` approach as it's a bit more 'expensive' than the classical 'drop a space at either end and hope tokenization did the rest' plan

Comment: @JosephWright correct :) I like `\tl_trim_spaces:n`, it is a great piece of code, but one has to either have erroneous spaces in a definition or try really hard (see the code in this question) to end up with multiple spaces. So my take on it is: If you end up with more than a single space, that's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: You can't reliably, as `pgfkeys` sometimes reparses things (this depends on the internals of the key handlers involved). However, for the keys defined with `/.initial`, you can put a single space after the equals sign. That will prevent the first brace-stripping happening internally that should only take place *after* outer spaces are stripped.

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{/WeirdKeys/weird/.initial=weird}%
\newcommand\Weird[1]{\pgfkeys{/WeirdKeys/.cd,#1}}%

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

Here I don't want spaces around weird: |\Weird{weird}|.

\Weird{weird= { weird }}

Here I do want spaces around weird: |\Weird{weird}|.

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]